# How to extract json data in an array using a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Hello guys I have a problem. And I don't know how to solve it. I am a beginner in ajax processing. I hope you can help me.

I have an ajax data from the success. And I want to put this in an array. Because I want to put the json data in an options select box.

Here's my code:

In my controller I have this

```
$('#state').on('change',function(){

            var state_code = $('#state').val();

            var city_url = '<?php echo site_url("locations/displayCity/' + state_code + '"); ?>';

            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: city_url,
                data: '',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function(i){

                    console.log(i)

                }

            });

        });
```

And here's the select box options that i need to fill using json data

```
<select id="city" name="city">
    <option value="">---Select City---</option>
</select>
```

Here's the json reponse

```
[{"id":"1054","name":"Altavas"},{"id":"1055","name":"Balete"},{"id":"1056","name":"Banga"},{"id":"1057","name":"Batan"},{"id":"1058","name":"Buruanga"},{"id":"1059","name":"Ibajay"},{"id":"1060","name":"Kalibo"},{"id":"1061","name":"Lezo"},{"id":"1062","name":"Libacao"},{"id":"1063","name":"Madalag"},{"id":"1064","name":"Makato"},{"id":"1065","name":"Malay"},{"id":"1066","name":"Malinao"},{"id":"1067","name":"Nabas"},{"id":"1068","name":"New Washington"},{"id":"1069","name":"Numancia"},{"id":"1070","name":"Tangalan"}]
```

In my console.log I have this:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
11: Object
length: 12
```

**proto**: Array[0]

If I clicked the arrow in the objects I will get this:

```
Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
id: "1028"
name: "Butuan City"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
id: "1029"
name: "Buenavista"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
11: Object
length: 12
__proto__: Array[0]
```

That's all guys. Thanks.

Comment: show your response data (json ) it will helpfull

Comment: Ok I will update my post

Answer (score 4):

just replace

```
success: function(i){
    console.log(i)
}
```

with

```
success: function(data){
    $.each($.parseJSON(data),function(index,value){
        $('#city').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
    });
}
```

Comment: JSON.parse(i) first so it will become object

Comment: I think the return value of my code is in object. Check my edit if I am right.

Answer (score 2):

Your response is already an array. Just iterate over it using `jQuery.each(i, function(index, item) {...})`

Comment: its `jQuery.each(array, function(index, item) {})` by the way

Answer (score 2):

use this -

```
$.each(i, function(key,val){

 $('#city').append("<option value='" + key + ">" + val + "</option>");

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  function(i){

     $.each(i,function(index,value){ 
       $("#city").append("<option value='"+value.id+"'>"+value.name+"</option>")
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use **append** by this it every time append on select box first make a string then set full html in select-box it is  fast then append

```
var str='';
$.each(i, function(index,value){
str +="<option value='"+value.id+"'>"+value.name+"</option>";


});
 $('#city').html(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand when you `console.log(i)`; you get the right response.
Now what you need to do, is to `JSON.parse` the object and then set it on the select option.

With my experince, thats the tricky part, because select option can not be auto set by html.

So here is what might be some usable code(if you want something to be prefixed).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var size =    $('select').children('option').length;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if ( $('select').children('option')[i].value === resultingObj.whatever)
        {
             $('select').children('option')[i].selected=true;
        }
    }
});
```

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: city_url,
           data: '',
           dataType: 'json',
           async: false,
           success: function(response){
            var resp_length = response.length;
            var option = '';
            for(var i = 0; i< resp_length;i++){
                option += '<option value="'+response[i].id+'">'+response[i].name+'</option>';
            }
            $('#city').append(option);//Opertation on DOM only one time.
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following script

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  ...
  success: function(response){
    var option = null;
    //iterate each json record
    $(response).each(function(index, record){

      //create option tag with value and record name
      option = $('<li>').attr('value', record.id).html(record.name);

      //append this option tag to select box
      $('#city').append(option);
    });
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

parse first your json to object then use $.each

```
success: function(i){
    json = JSON.parse(i);
    $.each(json,function(index,value){
        $('#city').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
    });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't append as well. I will try to create a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
var select=$('#city');
for (var j=0; j<i.length; j++)
{
   select.append('<option value="'+i[j].id+'">'+i[j].name+'</option>');
}
```

Comment: I dont think so, its working here: http://jsfiddle.net/A4fjL/ . By mistake i just used the variable name wrong :P

Comment: Ok I did that But it is not appending

Comment: What are you getting with `console.log(i[0].id)` ?

Answer (score 1):

From your code I modified it to do what you would like.

```
success: function(i)
{
var resultingObj = JSON.parse(i);

    for(var iterator = 0; iterator < resultingObj.length; iterator++)
    {
        //perform actions
        $('#city').append('<option value="' + resultingObj[iterator].id + '">' + resultingObj[iterator].name + '</option>');
    }
}
```

Comment: iterator is not a reserved word in javascript

Comment: Yeah running on very little sleep and caffeine. I'm working through it :P.